# where can I get springs source code?

Tags: java, spring

Hm, trying to find the spring framework's source code download, but can't!

Can someone help me out?

BTW, what exactly are the benefits of going with more commercial version of spring?

Comment: Have you tried the community downloads at springsource?

Comment: yes I have, can't find it in their at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check out or browse the source from Spring's <strike>[CVS](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=73357) or [Subversion](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=73357) (both obsolete)</strike> [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework) site.

As far as the commercial version of Spring, I believe it provides you with support and access to patches quicker.  Its all detailed on their [product page](http://www.springsource.com/services/enterprisesupport).

Answer (score 3):

Older source code (version 2 and before) is available in [zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/springframework/files/springframework/1.2.9/spring-framework-1.2.9.zip/download) files downloadable from http://sourceforge.net/projects/springframework/files/springframework/.

Comment: Source was removed from this location and replaced with a readme.

Comment: @javabrett, I really didn't understand your -1 for me. Just downloaded spring-framework-1.2.9.zip and spring-framework-2.5.5-with-dependencies.zip. And source code **present** in archive. May be you had fault with some particular version..

As I see in readme.txt in spring-framework-2.5.5.zip:
_Contents of the "-with-dependencies" distribution (~79 MB): ... * "src" contains the general Java source files for the framework _

Comment: Yeah my bad.  I've proposed an edit which when accepted should allow me to reverse my vote.  I think at the time I was fixated on finding source in a hosted Subversion server, which of course was not the original question, and source-code in a zip is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Source is already included in the normal Spring download. Check the `/dist` folder after you unzip it.

Comment: @BalusC, it's not in the `dist` directory, it's in the `src` directory.  And @mrblah, yes, the source is included in JAR files in that `src` directory; it's left as an exercise for the reader to figure out how to access that source code.

Answer (score 1):

- If you downloaded a bundle from the SpringSource website, it contains sources (under `src`).
- Or you could just checkout sources from their [public repository](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/).
- But if you just want to browse them, then [Fisheye](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-framework) might be more appropriate.
- Lots of site like [kickjava.com](http://kickjava.com/src/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java.htm) or [docjar.com](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java.html) also have sources online.
- And, if you are using Maven, sources jar are available in the [central repository](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/) (most IDEs allow to download them in one click).

Comment: Upvote for the Maven Central link, this is the best place to obtain springframework 2.0 and prior source bundles.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it [from Subversion](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/).

Comment: Not anymore, redirects to GitHub, but has 3.0.x source and onwards only.